# Are Piecewise continuous functions Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Are **Piecewise continuous** functions **Lipschitz continuous** as well?
I understand that Lipschitz continuous $\implies$ absolutely continuous, and I think Piecewise continuous functions can be thought of as absolutely continuous.

i.e., as per my understanding: $$ \text{Lipschitz continuous} \subseteq \text{Absolutely continuous} \subseteq \text{Uniformly continuous} $$
and $$ \text{Piecewise continuous} \subseteq \text{Absolutely continuous}. $$
Now my question is: where does **Lipschitz continuous** fits in the above relation with **Piecewise continuous**?

e.g.,
$ f(x) = 0 \  \text{for}\ x < 0\ \text{and}\ f(x) = x \  \text{for}\ x \ge 0 $

Can we consider a Lipschitz constant $L = 1$ to declare the above "Piecewise continuous" function Lipschitz continuous as well?

Comment: There is something wrong. Not every piecewise continuous function is absolutely continuous. In fact, not every CONTINUOUS function is absolutely continuous. Take, for instance, the cantor function.

Comment: @sranthrop: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @sranthrop: If I now restrict the class of piecewise continuous functions to have only finite number of points where the function is not differentiable, does that force to ensure the function to be absolutely continuous? (The function is considered to have finite slope everywhere.)

Comment: Using your first relations we see that every absolutely continuous function is continuous. This implies that a piecewise continuous function which is not continuous cannot be absolutely continuous, no matter if (or where) it is differentiable.

Comment: The OP is probably thinking about piecewise continuously **differentiable** functions (i.e. the function is continuous and the derivative is piecewise continuous). These are indeed locally Lipschitz as well as (locally) absolutely continuous.

Comment: @PhoemueX, can we then consider the function, in the example above, to be _globally_ Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant L=1 as it satisfies the norm inequality for the whole euclidean space R?

Comment: @neelarnab: Yes, that function **is** globally Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $L=1$.